# Flutter prevent button spamming

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, button

My app consists of a lot of buttons calling a webservice using async methods.

When the user spams buttons (e. g. login) the method get called more than once resulting in exceptions (Because the main menu opens more than once).

Can I somehow disable user inputs for the whole view, until the method has finished?
Or do I have to hardcode a boolean (buttonPressed) in every single view to prevent spamming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can show an overlay when the async method is called. This way you won't be able to make an interaction until the process finished.
2. If you don't want to block the whole UI and just want to disable the tap until the async call finishes, then wrap your button with stream builder and provide a boolean stream to it. If isAsyncCalling is false then make the onPressed visible else disable it.

Here is the code you can use..

```
class PreventMultipleTaps extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PreventMultipleTapsState createState() => _PreventMultipleTapsState();
}

class _PreventMultipleTapsState extends State<PreventMultipleTaps> {
  StreamController<bool> _controller = StreamController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<bool>(
            stream: _controller.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return RaisedButton(
                onPressed: snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data == false ? () {
                  print("On Tap");
                  _controller.add(true);
                  asyncCall();
                } : null, child: Text("Continue"),);
            }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<String> asyncCall() async {
    var result = "result";
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
    _controller.add(false);
    return result;
  }
}
```

3. You can also use the AbsorbPointer widget to block the user interaction.

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your whole tree in an `AbsorbPointer` (doesn't allow child clicks) or `IgnorePointer` (ignores all clicks) widget and toggle the `absorbing` or `ignoring` property to true (ignore) or false (allow) when the buttons are clicked.